# How can I refactor these two functions?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions.

```
function markAsPerforming(orderInd) {
    if (confirm('confirm?')) {
        $.get('server.php', {'action':'markAsPerforming', 'ind':orderInd}, function(data) {
            if (data != 'ok') {
                alert(data);
                loadOrders();
            } else {
                loadOrders();
            }
        });
    }
}

function deleteOrder(orderInd) {
    if (confirm('confirm?')) {
        $.get('server.php', {'action':'delOrder', 'ind':orderInd}, function(data) {
            if (data != 'ok') {
                alert(data);
                loadOrders();
            } else {
                loadOrders();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The main differences is the names of the functions, question in the confirm() and in the 'action' field in get request. I think better way refactoring these functions combine them into a single. Is that right? How better to unite them into single? Does it sense to combine them?

Comment: In your code sample, even the confirmation message is the same. You would only have to write a single function that takes an additional `action` argument.

Comment: At first glance they're exactly the same except for the `"action"` value. Isn't the refactor obvious?

Comment: You might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Nikita So pass that in too, although without knowing *exactly* what you want to actually do, the question is even more OT than it already is--this belongs on codereview, as meagar stated. But the more things are different than what you've posted, the more different the appropriate refactoring(s) will be.

Comment: @Nikita The function basically performs a server action, given a string action name and an order. I'd name it something that means essentially that, and rely on either the parameter value, or thin wrapper functions, to provide contextual info.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly makes sense to refactor into a single function. Just give it a more generic name and take a second `action` parameter and a third `confirm` parameter if necessary:

```
function orderAction(orderInd, action, confirm) {

    if (confirm(confirm)) {
        $.get('server.php', {'action': action, 'ind':orderInd}, function(data) {
            if (data != 'ok') {
                alert(data);
            }
            loadOrders();
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Updated as per Dave's suggestion. Also included a third parameter for confirmation message.

Comment: Delta that the redundant `loadOrders` should also be taken out, and I might flatten it to remove the confirmation flow nesting.

Comment: Oh yes, good spot, Dave :)

Comment: Actually, could you elaborate on the confirmation flow nesting part? (feel free to update my answer if it's easier, or post a new answer)

Comment: Sure. I'm not a fan of nesting ("code turned on its side isn't a graph of how awesome it is") and almost always prefer to return as early as possible, or restructure code to make it as flat as reasonable. In this case I'm ambivalent--everything is short. I might pull out the response handler into its own method e.g., https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/6390256 but meh.

Comment: That's pretty neat, thanks Dave!

Answer (score 2):

I think this way is a little more semantic. You have two separate actions which share some functionality.

```
function markAsPerforming(orderInd) {
    if (confirm('confirm?')) {
        doGet("markAsPerforming", orderInd);
    }
}

function deleteOrder(orderInd) {
    if (confirm('confirm?')) {
        doGet("delOrder", orderInd);
    }
}

function doGet(action, orderInd) {
    $.get('server.php', {'action':action, 'ind':orderInd}, function(data) {
            if (data != 'ok') {
                alert(data);
                loadOrders();
            } else {
                loadOrders();
            }
    });
}
```

It's not a good idea having one big function with lots of parameters. It's better to have lots of small functions which get called by another grouping function. It's more semantic and more easy to mantain small functions rather than adding more parameters to a big one.

Continuing on the same concept you can refactor even further:

```
function doGet(action, orderInd) {
    $.get('server.php', {'action': action, 'ind':orderInd}, success);
}
function success(data) {
   if (data != 'ok') {
       alert(data);
   }
   loadOrders(); //loadOrders was being called regardless of data, so I took it out
}
```

Note that you now have 4 functions instead of 2, but they all perform a very specific task. In the end, it all depends on how much you think you will need this functions to change and how much you think they will grow over time. For example, in the future you might want to call a different url in the server for different actions, and it would make sense to split doGet in two different functions and bake (hardcode) the parameters for each action. Or you might want to add an error handler, which would be better as a sepparate function rather than clutter the $.get call.

Anyway, this is general advice which will start making more sense as you start coding bigger programs. I know it's hard to resist the temptation of creating "[god objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)" that do everything because things start small and seem manageable, but in the end the best is to avoid doing that and favour code readability and mantainability.

Comment: This is my favourite answer :)

Comment: Good! Thanks. I am beginner developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor like this, where `actionNm` will be equal to `delOrder` or `markAsPerforming`

```
function onConfirm(orderInd, actionNm) {
if (confirm('confirm?')) {
    $.get('server.php', {'action':actionNm, 'ind':orderInd}, function(data){
        if (data != 'ok') {
            alert(data);
            loadOrders();
        } else {
            loadOrders();
        }
    });
}
}
```